# How do I get past the first dead girl in Chapter 1?

Tags: doorways

In the first chapter, there's a section where you have to cross what looks like a ruined wooden bridge.  It might not be too difficult if there was light, but the psychopath I'm chasing appears to have remedied that for me by taking out nearly all the torches.  Just when I think I'm nearly across, the silhouette of what looks like a girl materializes on the plank in front of me.

[image: Dead girl]

What happens if you get too close... well, I'll just post the message the game gives you.

[image: Find Another Way]

> FIND ANOTHER WAY

I can't see another way around after backtracking a little.  How do I get past her?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I looked around a bit more and it turns out there's another board you can jump to just to the left of deadgirl.  You'll have to get pretty close to her in order to be close enough to jump to it though.

Since the image below is so dark, I've highlight the important bits with colours.  You can see it (slightly) better in the actual game.

[image: ANOTHER WAY]